# Material-table CustomSort doesn't work with Dates

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I receive a column from api that contains Dates + _number (example: "20/12/2019_1" as a string). The sort function will group counting data as a string and not as a Date column. Which means i need to do a customSort.
So i created a function to transform that string into a Date object, but when i return the value nothing happens...

**Columns:**

[image: Columns]

**utils.js:**

[image: utils.js]

The formatLot function is working as expected since i wanna Sort value as type Date.

**Result from formatLot function:**

[image: Result from formatLot function]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the custom sort incorrectly.

As seen in the [docs](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/sorting), you have to return the comparison of two dates as a number, but you are only returning the date object.

Change it to and it will work:

```
customSort: (a,b) => formatLot(a.test).getTime() - formatLot(b.test).getTime()
```

Comment: The documentation example uses lengths to do a customSort, i can't use lengths in this case and i couldn't find something similiar.
I think you miss understood the issue. I'm not returning a string, i'm returning an object. localeCompare is only for strings. Infortunately the changes you made doesn't help me in this case

Comment: II updated my answer, I thought you would return the string. This should work.

Comment: Still doesn't work. i changed to:
`customSort: (a,b) => formatLot(a.test).getTime() - formatLot(b.test).getTime()`

and i received an **TypeError: Object(...)(...).getTime is not a function**

Comment: can you put that in a sandbox, so I can take a look at your code?

Comment: Yes, of course... Apperantly it's working on codesandbox...
[https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-customsort-date-cgppk]

Comment: Ok, i found the issue! I pass null values too and that's where the crash happens... i need to make a validation for nulls and it's working perfectly. Thank you very much for the help, you saved me a lot of time